# When to use JViewport.getExtentSize() vs. JViewport.getSize()?

Tags: java, swing, jviewport

Looking at the source, it seems that JViewport.getExtentSize() always returns the same value as JViewport.getSize() (The same holds for setExtentSize() and setSize()). Why do both exist? Is it just an alias to make it clearer in code that you are getting the size (visible extent) of the viewport.view? Is there something else happening in the UI delegates and/or something related to plaf that I'm missing? Or, does getExtentSize() exist purely for symmetry with setExtentSize(), and the latter exists to provide different notification than setSize() (I note  ChangeListeners are notified when setExtentSize() is called)?

Comment: It's possible the the choice to make another method (`getExtentSize`) could have been done to remove any confusion that `getSize` might have caused (as logically, the size of the view can be larger the the viewable area of the view port).  It may also have been done because in the past `getExtentSize` may have functioned differently then `getSize` and the implementation was changed was changed later.  The reasoning is impossible to know and you would need to find and ask the development teams from 15+ years ago

Comment: @MadProgrammer - fair point. I'll revise the title as it doesn't get to the real point. Understanding the history isn't the point; understanding if there is a meaningful difference in the current implementation that helps guide one in the proper selection of getExtentSize() vs getSize() is the point. However, I'll point out that the viewport view's size has nothing to do with the viewport's extentSize.

Comment: Simply from a documentation point of view, the `getExtentSize` clear defines the expectation of the method, where as `getSize` is ambiguous in it's meaning within the context of the component. While, currently, there might not be any difference, it allows future implementations to change how the `extentSize` is changed, without adversely affecting other code...